# Selecting newest attributes from a number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a system that receives updates to data located in a table. The updates have null allowed for all columns, which means that if a null is received then any old value should just stay the same.

The table also contains both numeric columns (Which I call values), and non numeric columns (Which I call attributes.)

The values should simply be added together... but for the attributes the newest update should be chosen.

Really the problem is just to get the newest update for all the attributes, but I've included the values columns just because it is a part of the real life problem.

The solution runs today, but is not very stable. It simply processes the updates one by one, making sure that they are read in the same order as they have arrived.

Unfortunately this sometimes leads to a very high number of loops, since there can easily be thousands of different "arrival times" on a single day.
This means that every time an update is received, even for just one row... I create a whole new result table, with perhaps only one change.

I would like this to run as a single SQL, instead of doing a lot of loops outside the server.

Another problem is that there is a quite large number of value columns and attribute columns. (Like 70-100 in total.)

I've created an SQL fiddle, to play around with the problem... but my current best idea is to use cross apply (I use MSSQL server 2017, so this is a possibility.)

sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0a8a9/2

(The fiddle shows an example, and explains a few extra things along the way.)

Even with the example with only 3 rows that need to be examined for "newest" the code gets out of hand.
If I were to implement this it would be totally unmanageable, and I'm also not really sure what the optimizer might think of these 40-50 joins/applys.

How can this be achieved? 
As a single SQL (Lots of CTE's etc are allowed.)
Without adding a huge bunch of lines for each attribute?

If I've ended up in this problem due to some bad design, please let me know as well. Especially if a slight change in the design can fix the problem.

Comment: Sounds like you need `update` or maybe `merge` and a whole bunch of `attr = coalesce(newattr, attr)` and `val = val + coalesce(newval, 0)`

Comment: The coalesce-approach is what I'm already doing, but it looks at two rows at a time only... thus forcing me to loop through all updates until I have the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query. Please double check the syntax.

```
;WITH cte_dates (ItemNumber, CorrectionTime_A1, CorrectionTime_A2, CorrectionTime_A3)
AS
(
  SELECT ItemNumber, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute1 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CorrectionTime END) AS  CorrectionTime_A1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute2 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CorrectionTime END) AS  CorrectionTime_A2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Attribute3 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE CorrectionTime END) AS  CorrectionTime_A3
  FROM Updates
  GROUP BY ItemNumber
)

SELECT u.ItemNumber,
  MAX(CASE WHEN u.CorrectionTime=m.CorrectionTime_A1 THEN Attribute1 ELSE NULL END) AS Attribute1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN u.CorrectionTime=m.CorrectionTime_A2 THEN Attribute2 ELSE NULL END) AS Attribute2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN u.CorrectionTime=m.CorrectionTime_A3 THEN Attribute3 ELSE NULL END) AS Attribute3,
  SUM(Value1) AS Value1,
  SUM(Value2) AS Value2,
  SUM(Value3) AS Value3
FROM cte_dates m
INNER JOIN Updates u
ON m.ItemNumber=u.ItemNumber
GROUP BY u.ItemNumber;
```

Comment: It surely works!
What a beautiful way of turning the problem solution upside down, compared to what I tried.
First find all the most recent correction for each attribute, and then use this information to find the result.